# Simulating a railway network

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures, graph

I wanted to simulate a railway network where there would be stations, trains and routes connecting each station. So how do you think I should attempt to model this? I thought of using graphs taking station as vertex and edges as routes. Also since there will be tens of trains and stations and hence hundreds of routes so should I model the database as a graph in mysql or should I write create a php program containing the graph which retrieves info from the database?

I am a relatively beginner programmer and be glad with some help as I am very confused at this moment. Any other better idea is also welcome.

Comment: No sir not homework. I am doing this on my own.

Comment: What do you want to simulate exactly? The entity models (including relationship/propertie etc) only? Or more advanced one (e.g. the day to day running of the trains along the routes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for this. I know there are stored procedures online (to create the database of stations) somewhere I just can't find them right now. Should help you get started though.

Comment: who said he wanted to do any kind of efficient routing?

Comment: like i said there are stored procedures online that will help him with his issue if he looks for dijkstra's algo.  i just can't find him right now.

Comment: Obviously I would need dijkstra put the problem as I said is should I model the database as a graph?? or create a graph design in php and then retrieve it from a database??